# in what order does cosmosDB return results when values being ordered by are the same?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm facing an issue where results are returned in seemingly random order when ordering by a field for which two results have the same value. this is likely due to asyncronous data ingestion, but I'm trying to pin it down and would like any further insight.

Consider this.
I insert 2 documents into my db:

```
{ 
  "id" : 0,
  "speed" : 10,
  "activity" : 1
}

{
  "id" : 1,
  "speed" : 10,
  "activity" : 2
}
```

and then run the following query below, the results will return in the same order every time (i.e. activity=1 record returns before activity=2). however, if I insert the same set again (with different IDs), the same query might return the new records in opposite order (i.e. activity=2 returns before activity=1)

```
SELECT * FROM c 
order by c.speed
```

so my question is, what does the ordering by fall back to when the values being ordered by are the same for a set of results? I'd assume it falls back to time of creation for each result. if so, is there a way to see the time a record was inserted into cosmos? the order doesn't appear to be controlled by any of the fields generated by cosmos (_rid,_etag,_ts,_self) - from my testing, the _ts field value doesn't have the precision to determine the order of records created this close together.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you order on speed and id? If you introduce a unique field in the sorting you will always get the same order when retrieving the documents. A somewhat similara discussion can be found here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264287/pagination-while-sorting-a-non-unique-text-column

Comment: Thanks for the response Anupam. That is an option, but currently not how the application is set up in production so I'm trying to get an idea of how cosmos operates without this. Creating the various composite keys for multiple order by clauses would be laborious and isn't high priority (in actuality the documents consist of several key/values, the example above is overly simplified).